# GSI on DynamoDB

Tags: indexing, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, database-indexes, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have dynamoDB table for order processing with following structure.

[image]

I have few more properties and I want to filter orders based on the status. For now I used scan method to get orders based on the status. But I would like to implement query statement to achieve more efficiency during query execution for this. How can I implement query statement to filter orders based on the status property ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a GSI with STATUS as the partition key...

Then in the query, you [tell it to use the GSI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.Reading).

```
{
    "TableName": "YourTable",
    "IndexName": "StatusIndex",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "status = :v_status",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":v_status": {"S": "FILLED"}
    },
}
```